# php if statement ignores condition

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if the user is from certain countries and not from ip address, than enter the if the following statement checks for `$COUNTRY` but ignors the ip check condition

```
if($COUNTRY == "USA" || $COUNTRY == "CAN" && $ipc != "1x.1x.1x.1x" && $ipc != "2x.2x.2x.2x"){
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question?

Comment: @mtndesign what more do you need to know?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`if(($COUNTRY == "USA" || $COUNTRY == "CAN") && $ipc != "1x.1x.1x.1x" && $ipc != "2x.2x.2x.2x")`

You want to use `( )` around the `||` condition so that PHP evaluates it correctly

This is just like in math, the use of order of operations.

Comment: oh i was so close... thanks! :)

Answer (score 11):

Do you know about [precedence](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)?

```
if(($COUNTRY == "USA" || $COUNTRY == "CAN") && $ipc != "1x.1x.1x.1x" && $ipc != "2x.2x.2x.2x"){
```